# Why I get Access Denied error from Loopback4 while able to connect from MySql workbench using same credentials

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, loopback

I am trying to run todo list example in loopback 4. I use MySql as the backend db on a different server. The problem I am facing is while I could connect to the database from MySql Workbench, I get the following error when I try making the db connection from loopback 4 using the same credentials.

Any help is appreciated.

---

```
Connection fails: Error: ER_DBACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'dev1'@'%' to database 'todo'
It will be retried for the next request.

C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47
  var err  = new Error(code + ': ' + packet.message);
             ^
Error: ER_DBACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'dev1'@'%' to database 'todo'
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:123:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:525:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:119:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:48:16)
    at MySQL.connect (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\loopback-connector-mysql\lib\mysql.js:90:17)
    at Object.initializeDataSource [as initialize] (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\loopback-connector-mysql\lib\mysql.js:44:28)
    at DbDataSource.DataSource.setup (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:513:19)
    at new DataSource (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\datasource.js:145:8)
    at new DbDataSource (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\src\datasources\db.datasource.ts:20:5)
    at C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\@loopback\context\src\resolver.ts:73:14
    at Object.transformValueOrPromise (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\@loopback\context\src\value-promise.ts:270:12)
    at Object.instantiateClass (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\@loopback\context\src\resolver.ts:66:35)
    at C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\@loopback\context\src\binding.ts:533:29
    at Binding._getValue (C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\@loopback\context\src\binding.ts:410:14)
    at C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\@loopback\context\src\binding.ts:305:23
    at C:\Users\rames\GitHub\todo-list\node_modules\@loopback\context\src\resolution-session.ts:114:13
```

Comment: so `'dev1'@'%'` is the username? At a guess there's something you've done wrong in your code

Comment: No, user name is dev1. The connection string specified in the datasource config file is mysql://dev1:dev1@22.22.132.230/todo (This is the format specified by loopback)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there was a typo in database name in the connection string. I fixed it and I am able to connect now.
@jaromanda Thank you.